# LINQ vs SQL Stored procedure - performance and where filtering (LIKE vs CONTAINS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, linq, t-sql

I have an Azure Cloud Service that currently connects to a SQL Stored procedure that does a select *  with no param. The service returns json. About 10k rows in the table. the code has a list contains to filter on one column.

```
 List<clsSitesData> lstFilteredData = lstSearchData.Where(s => s.LS_TITLE.ToLower().Contains(SearchData.ToLower())).ToList();
```

Surprisingly consuming the service from a jquery/knockout client is very fast.

From the code it would seem I'm loading the entire table into a list every time.

First, I would think i would benefit from paramaters in the stored procedure to limit the returned data right?  Also, maybe some SQL indexing - keep in mind SQL is on Azure.

But, what about LINQ directly to the table and no Stored procedure with LINQ  should I expect that to be faster or better than the above?

I'm not having a performance issues right now, but I do need to condition on more columns.  Also wonder if pulling all rows every time is costing me in Azure CPU hours.

Comment: would there be a reason that a client wants to look through 10000 rows for something? Maybe limit it to the top # of rows and then add filters so they can tighten their search down to a few rows to work with?

Comment: One question at a time.  You are asking about LINQ, SP, parameter, and index and you have no specific performance problem at this time.

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way to share data is by deploying an OData Service. There are OData clients, like datajs and Breeze.js that allows you to work in a fashion similar to LINQ to query data: it can filter, page, order, and even cache data, and update it on the server.

Google for 'SQL Azure OData', and you'll find information on how to do it like this: [Creating and Hosting OData Service in Azure](http://venkateshnarayanan.wordpress.com/2013/05/03/creating-and-hosting-odata-service-in-azure/).

For more information on breeze, [look here](http://www.breezejs.com/). [datajs offers less functionalities](http://datajs.codeplex.com/), but you can also use it.

BTW, I forgot to say that OData doesn't support something similar to LIKE, but you can use `startswith`, `endswith` and `substringof` which cover part of the LIKE cases.